# Получение задач с подзадачами пользователя Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Есть модель Task, у нее есть связь для получения подзадач:

```
public function children(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'parent_id')
        ->with('children');
}
```

Но сейчас, натянув разделение задач по пользователям, нужно **получать все задачи с подзадачами, принадлежащие конкретному пользователю**. В модели User есть следующий метод:

```
public function tasks(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Task::class);
}
```

Но таким образом теряется "вложенность", то есть дочерние задачи не берутся. Прошу, предложите идеи как реализовать получение задач с подзадачами у пользователя.

Comment: `$user->with('tasks.children');`